# Facebook Graph API & Koala: How to find relationship status of a user's 'friend'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api, koala

I have built a rails app using Devise, Omniauth and Koala. With this I have been able to pull down all of the current user's friends:

```
  @graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(@token)
  @friends = @graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
```

and I have been able to get the current user's relationship status:

```
  @graph = Koala::Facebook::GraphAPI.new(@token)
  @relationship = @graph.get_object("me")
```

**What I haven't been able to figure out is how to make a call for all of the current user's friends that also includes their relationship status**. I think I need to include some incremental argument / parameter in the get_connections("me", "friends") call, but I don't know what that incremental argument parameter would be.

Inside my config/initializers/omniauth.rb file, I have included the following in the Facebook scope:

{:scope => 'publish_stream,offline_access,email,user_relationships,friends_relationships'}

Any help with this specific Koala question? Is there a list anywhere that shows a bunch of different examples of Koala and how to use it to make the various different calls of Facebook data?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

you need to get permission first

```
redirect_to session['oauth'].url_for_oauth_code(:permissions=>'friends_relationships')   
@graph.get_connections('me','friends',:fields=>"name,gender,relationship_status")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@graph.fql_query("select uid, relationship_status from user where uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())"
```

make fql calls. They are much much faster to use in large numbers.